# How is segmentation useful?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Recently I began to study computer vision. In a series of text, I encountered "segmentation" which creates a group of pixels (super-pixels) based on pixel features.

Here is an example:

[image]

But, I'm not sure how do they use super-pixels at the first place. Do we use it for paint-like visualization? Or some kinds of object detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segmentation you did for this image is useless since it does not split any thing useful. But consider this segmentation for example:

[image]

It splits the duck and the other objects from the background.

You can here find some useful application of Image Segmentation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation#Applications

Answer (score 1):

Usually super pixel alone is not enough to perform segmentation. It can be the first step in performing segmentation. But further processing need to be done to perform segmentation.
In one of the papers I have read they use seam processing to measure the energy of the edges. 
There is another paper for jitendra Malik about using super pixels in segmentation.